# Count number of times each value occurs in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 

test_values = []

test_values.append(np.array([1,0,1]))
test_values.append(np.array([1,0,1]))
test_values.append(np.array([0,1,1]))

test_values

df = pd.DataFrame(test_values)
```

rendering this dataframe produces :

```
   0  1  2
0  1  0  1
1  1  0  1
2  0  1  1
```

I'm attempting to count the number of times each value occurs in column, so for above dataframe the following should be produced :

```
1 occurs 2, 0 occurs 0. 
0 occurs 2, 1 occurs 1. 
1 occurs 3, 0 occurs 0.
```

Using .values() :

```
for i in range(0 , df.shape[1]) : 
    print(df.iloc[:,i].value_counts().values)
```

produces :

```
[2 1]
[2 1]
[3]
```

The label has been removed from each column. How to access the associated label for each count ? So can produce  :

```
1 occurs 2, 0 occurs 0. 
0 occurs 2, 1 occurs 1. 
1 occurs 3, 0 occurs 0.
```

Comment: you can try to use `value_counts()` for each column separately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there are expected only `0` and `1` values add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) for add missing values - reindex by list of expected values:

```
for i in range(0 , df.shape[1]) : 
    a = df.iloc[:,i].value_counts().reindex([0,1], fill_value=0)
    print (', '.join('{} occurs {}.'.format(k, v) for k, v in a.items()))

0 occurs 1., 1 occurs 2.
0 occurs 2., 1 occurs 1.
0 occurs 0., 1 occurs 3.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate a series via [`pd.Series.items`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.items.html):

```
for i in range(0 , df.shape[1]):
    counts = df.iloc[:,i].value_counts()
    gen = (f'{key} occurs {value} times' for key, value in counts.items())
    print(*gen, sep=', ')
```

It's not clear how you expect to deduce zero counts, so I have not assumed this is a requirement. The result gives:

```
1 occurs 2 times, 0 occurs 1 times
0 occurs 2 times, 1 occurs 1 times
1 occurs 3 times
```